# Can I get on Javascript resource to load another one?

Tags: javascript, load

I have a scenario where I want a web page to contain a `<link>` to one Javascript resource, and have that resource load two other Javascript resources from the same webserver.  Is this possible?  Can it be done in a browser-independent fashion?

This may sound a bit unusual, but there are complicated reasons why I'd like to be able to do this, and why combining the resources into a single file is ... awkward.

Comment: may be putting all in one file is complex , but why not having three script tags ?

Comment: The link is in an HTML file that I don't want to modify ... if I can avoid it.  (The site is composed using Maven WAR file overlays, and I don't "own" the module that contributes the HTML file.  I can copy the file and modify it, but then I've got a problem tracking changes made to the original version.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm not wrong Javascript resource is nothing but your *.js files, Right?
So You can include any number of js in your page, with `<script>` tag.
e.g.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="MyDomain/js/abc.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="MyDomain/js/xyz.js"></script>
```

Also, in one js file, you can import another js file, by calling following function:

```
function IncludeJavaScript(jsFile)
{
  document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="'
    + jsFile + '"></scr' + 'ipt>'); 
}
```

**EDIT:**

Or another way to write same function:

```
function includeJS( jsPath )
{
    var js = document.createElement("script");
    js.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
    js.setAttribute("src", jsPath);
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(js);
};
```

Call these functions inside you js file.

Comment: Later I thought, you are looking `@import` in JavaScript! Like we use in CSS.. For css: `@import url("/ami/css/style.css");`

Answer (score 1):

It appears what you're looking for is typically referred to as [On-Demand javascript](http://ajaxpatterns.org/On-Demand_Javascript)